# Running two java source folders in Eclipse where one is a sub-folder of the other

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to run some java code in Eclipse (Mars) downloaded from a link in the following paper:
http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1001059#s4

A direct link to this code is:
http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~rpsysbio/pada

To run this code in Eclipse I initially run .java files in the subfolder "src/sbml2spa", which works fine.  To run the next part of the program I need to run .java files from "src."  I have tried taking the files from "sbml2spa" and placing them directly into "src", but this causes the initial .java files from the "sbml2spa" subfolder to fail.

Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an exclude of the `sbml2spa` folder in the definition of the `src` folder.

- Right-click project and select "Properties".
- Select `Java Build Path` on the left.
- Select `Source` tab.
- Expand `src` path.
- Select `Excluded: ...` and click `Edit`.
- Click `Add` in the `Exclusion patterns` section.
- Type `sbml2spa/**` and click `OK`.

The Java compiler will now ignore the `sbml2spa` folder when compiling from that Source Path.